# Share POJO Entity Data Classes between Android and Spring projects

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, android-studio, intellij-idea

How can I reference, add, link, depend on java classes defined in a different project or library without copy / paste?

For:

- Android Studio
- IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Android Studio

### AndroidProjectRoot/settings.gradle

*Before*

```
include ':app'
```

*After*

```
include ':app', ':common'
project(':common').projectDir = new File('../common')
```

### AndroidProjectRoot/app/build.gradle

*Before*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
}
```

*After*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
}
```

#### THEN...

- Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Allows Android Studio project to reference an external project (at the same directory level as AndroidProjectRoot/, without making a copy of the Java Library inside your Android Project.

### Library Project / Module

You'll need a basic build.gradle for the Library/Module.  The following will suffice.  The dependencies are just for example (only use as appropriate), in case your module is a bunch of objects being handled by a DAO like OrmLite.

#### Library Project Root/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:4.48'
}
```

## IntelliJ IDEA

**Reference Library as Module**

- File -> Project Structure
- (Left Column) Select "Modules"
- (Middle Column, top left) Click + button
- Import Module
- Select top-level directory that contains Java Library, e.g. common (see note below)
- Click OK

**Add Dependency so you can use import statements**

- (Middle Column, list of Modules) Select your main module (not the one you just added)
- (Right rectangular area, bottom left) Click + button
- Select 3 Module Dependency...
- Select your added module (e.g. :common)
- Click OK
- Click OK (closes Project Structure)
- IDEA should now rebuild gradle and add your library as a module to the project structure with a folder icon (with tiny blue square) beside the name

Note:

If your Library is structured like:

common/
common/build.gradle
common/src
common/src/java
common/src/java/main
common/src/java/main/com
common/src/java/main/com/your
common/src/java/main/com/your/package
common/src/java/main/com/your/package/YourClass.java

### Further Reading

[Mathias Hauser - Spring Boot JPA Multiple Projects](https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/how-to-configure-spring-boot-with-jpa-and-multiple-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the pojo project as a module for the android project:

All you need to do is open one project, and then "**Import Module**", so you select the other "**Project**", this way they will be able to see each other resources and codes.

From there it would be as easy as using an **import** as long as the access modifiers allow you to do such import (public for example)